# How do i keep a row of HTML items fluid, but ensure they have equal elements per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a set of 6 elements inside a parent element. The 6 elements need to be fluid enough that when their parent element is at its shortest, the elements stack in 6 rows of one. As the parent element is stretched out, they begin to stack evenly, so the only possible combinations will be 6 rows of 1, 2 rows of 3, 3 rows of 2 or 1 row of 6.

I have a JSBin where I've been trying to prove this out, with little success; http://jsbin.com/mawomu/2/edit.

Comment: have you tried media queries at different max-widths? Probably not an ideal solution but it could work

Comment: Media queries wont work unfortunately, as I need to allow the user to resize the parent element, and I can do media queries for individual elements.

Comment: So this wouldn't work? (would need to continue with higher widths or set up differently) http://jsbin.com/zinixiha/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Completing @deebs suggestion with @media

http://jsbin.com/jehequna/1/edit

This is highly 'volatile' as it depends on border, margin and padding widths.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 330px){
  .items li
    {
      min-width: 100px; 
    }  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 363px){
  .items li
    {
      min-width: 113px; 
    }  
}
@media screen and (min-width: 477px){
  .items li
    {
      min-width: 151px; 
    }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 630px){
  .items li
    {
      min-width: 100px; 
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work as the element needs to be any size - in your jsbin, if you set the size of .items to 500px, it breaks. Media queries cannot be used unfortunately.

Comment: Are you saying that the `ul.items` is set at a fixed width? Are you trying to have one definition of `.items li` that works with multiple `.items` (e.g. `.shorter` , `.shortest`)?

Comment: Actually, in the concrete implementation, `ul.items` is user resizable thanks to absolutely positioned drag handles around it. Meaning it is completely fluid and can be whatever size the user specifies. `.shorter`/`.shortest` were just trying to emulate the complexity of this.

Comment: I think you will be limited to a script solution. I don't know of a way to accomplish this with just CSS.